# Retrieving ISP Hostname

Tags: android, networking, hostname

I have this project where I have to retrieve my Isp's hostname.
I tried using this class but it returned to me my phone's information and I want the Isp's.

```
public class NetworkInterfaceTest extends InstrumentationTestCase {
    private final String TAG = NetworkInterfaceTest.class.getSimpleName();

    public void testNetworkName() throws Exception {
        Enumeration<NetworkInterface> it_ni = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
        while (it_ni.hasMoreElements()) {
            NetworkInterface ni = it_ni.nextElement();
            Enumeration<InetAddress> it_ia = ni.getInetAddresses();
            if (it_ia.hasMoreElements()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "++ NI:   " + ni.getDisplayName());
                while (it_ia.hasMoreElements()) {
                    InetAddress ia = it_ia.nextElement();
                    Log.i(TAG, "-- IA:   " + ia.getCanonicalHostName());
                    Log.i(TAG, "-- host: " + ia.getHostAddress());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I.e I want the results retrieved by the website https://www.whoismyisp.org/ in my app.

Answer (score 0):

DONE!
I ended up parsing the json data retrieved from http://ip-api.com/json